# Python recognizing hyphens (-) as 0, want NANs though

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nan, xlsx

I have an xlsx file where there are hyphens for some values. Upon clicking on the hyphens in the Excel sheet, they turn into 0 I noticed, too.

I am bringing this xlsx file into Python and even if I put **na_values='-'**... etc. at the very beginning of reading the file (**pd.read_excel**), Python will not recognize the hyphens by anything else other than 0. For my use case, this is wrong.

How can I make these hyphens into NANs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an Excel caused problem.  Excel often formats zeros as "-" in specific formats, such as currency.  If they are showing up as 0s in Excel when you click them, then they are actually 0s, not the display format, e.g., "-".

This raises the question, are the dashes distinct from what you believe are actual true 0s?  If so, this must be distinguished somehow.  If not and all 0s are actually NaN, replace the 0s with NaN.

However, from what you've shared thus far, it sounds like you may have fallen victim to someone else's poorly formatted Excel workbook.

Comment: Interesting. Idea how I can deal with these values inside of Excel? Looks like I will need to manually change them to NAN. I tried CTRL + H etc., did not work for me.

Comment: If you want pandas to treat them as NaN, I'd recommend removing all data from the column, otherwise, you could replace them with a string, but then since pandas allows mixed data types, cast it with `pandas.to_numeric(your_col, errors='coerce')`, which will convert any non-numeric field to a NaN.